# Prove if n is an irrational number then -n is so.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I'm a bit confused how I could prove this, I'm new to learning how to 'prove' things so I would appreciate any help.

Given n is an irrational number, trying to prove -n is also irrational.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $-n$ is rational then $-(-n) $ is rational (prove it using definition of rational numbers) so $n$ is rational, a contradiction.

Comment: This is circular reasoning because it assumes that x (= -n) is rational implies -x is rational, which is exactly what the OP is trying to prove.

Comment: That can be proven explicitly considering the form of rational numbers explicitly.

Comment: That means you first explicitly prove the OP's statement (call it P) as you wrote in your comment, and then use P to prove P (as you wrote in your answer). The second part is not necessary.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer little bit giving a hint where he should check explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $-n$ is a rational number; then we can write $-n$ as a quotient:

$$-n=\frac{p}{q}$$

where $p,q$ are integers and $q$ is non-zero. Thus we may multiply both sides of the equation by $-1$ to obtain:

$$n=\frac{-p}{q}$$

deducing that $n$ is also a rational number; this, however, is a contradiction, so we must in fact have $-n$ being irrational.